# How do i get a .wav sound to play?

Tags: java, android, file, audio, wav

Im making an app, and i want it to make a sound when a activity is opened , the sound file is in `R.raw.sound_file` , if someone could do some example code to make my app play a sound that would be great.

Answer (score 12):

doesn't the `android.media.MediaPlayer` class do this?

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Example: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html

Step 2 of the example says:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file_1);
mp.start();
```

In your case, I'd use the `onStart()` inside your Activity class:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
   ... 
   protected void onStart() {
      super.onStart();
      MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound_file_1);
      mp.start();
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: i dont know what to put as the context , ive tried putting it as null but the app just force closes

Comment: The context should be your Activity (or Service, BroadcastReceiver, ...) from which you call this.

But in your case: When you want to play the sound when the application first launches, you could start the MediaPlayer (as described above) from Application.onCreate(), this way I suspect the audio to be played earlier. But do not, this will play the audio always, also if another task starts one of your other Activities (if this is possible).

Comment: As MrSnowflake points out, the Activity class itself extends Context: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html have you tried passing that in? 

The doc page for Context lists all direct and indirect subclasses:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

Comment: I updated the solution to show how to do this in your Activity onStart() method.

Answer (score 4):

I have experience using the MediaPlayer object for an android app I created, and I discovered the following:

- Wav files have problems in MediaPlayer if they have a bitrate of 32kbps, but wav files of higher bit rates seem to play ok, even if it is a large wav file it will play ok as long as it has the higher bitrate.
- If at all possible, use mp3 files for your audio, I encountered no problems whatsoever with mp3 audio files using the MediaPlayer object, so that is the best way to go, using google there are lots of different kinds of mp3 sounds available free from rings and dings, to dog barks, and cat meows, or whatever kind of sound you are looking for.

Comment: I also have problems reading WAV files with MediaPlayer. Linux command `file` on the problematic file says: *RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, MPEG Layer 3, mono 44100 Hz*

Answer (score 1):

Try with my code, It's works perfectly. Also you need to have the sound file .wav en res/raw

```
public class PianoActivity extends Activity {

private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_piano);
    setupUI();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
}

private void setupUI() {
    findViewById(R.id.doo).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            managerOfSound();
        }
    });
}

private void managerOfSound() {
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.doo);
    if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    } else {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.reset();
            mp.release();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
this worked for me by using the application context as follows:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
   ... 
   protected void onStart() {
      super.onStart();
      Context appContext = getApplicationContext();
      MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(appContext , R.raw.sound_file_1);
      mp.start();
   }
   ...
}
```

Also, don't forget to call mp.release() once you're done

Another,preferred option is to use the SoundPool class