# Issue with playing sound file in Android Studio

Tags: android, audio

I stuck in trouble with playing a .wax file (.wax not .wav). I read Android Supported Media Formats, but It doesn't support for this type file.
How can I play this file in Android Studio?
is Convert WAX to MP3 a good choice? Or is there another solution?

Thanks all.

Comment: You can try this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883883/playing-short-wav-files-android

Comment: According to [this page](http://all-streaming-media.com/faq/streaming-media/Metafiles-WAX-Windows-Media-audio-redirector.htm) they are not audio files but instead point to streamable audio files. Maybe you could extract the URL from the .wax file and stream it with the MediaPlayer(?)