# Linking a sound file to a string value

Tags: java, android, string

```
private String sL[] = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j",
"k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w",
"x", "y", "z", "ç", "à", "é", "è", "û", "î" };
```

Although that code works. I don't really want it. I want each button to make a different sound.So to produce a sound in java you something [like that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458833/how-do-i-get-a-wav-sound-to-play)

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
... 
protected void onStart() {
super.onStart();
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound_file_1);
mp.start();
}
...
}
```

I have a wav file for every letter, so a should play a.wav and so on. I was hoping to create a loop from a to z and to play each wav that way

it's not really onStart(), it's more like whenever a button is pressed, play a different sound but that's not the point. I want to pass a different sound for each element of that string.

Comment: I don't see what immutability has to do with this. I think you want a `Map`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis What do you think is the best title for that question Sir?

Comment: It had nothing to do with immutability, I changed it to something that's ontopic. To your answer: create a `Map<String, SoundFile>` and use that to look up the correct soundfile for each string (I use `SoundFile`, change it to the appropriate type. I don't know what it is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use the array you've created?

```
 For(int i = 0; i< sL.length; i++){
      String wavFileName = sl[i] + ".wav";
     // do whatever you need to do here
 }
```

For on demand (press a button get a specific sound) then Jeroen's idea of using a map will work.